# Unable to find below classes in hibernate-search 6

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-search

We are in process of migrating hibernate-search 5 to hibernate-search 6.
While migrating we are not able to find below classes in hibernate-search 6 api

import org.hibernate.search.bridge.FieldBridge;
import org.hibernate.search.bridge.LuceneOptions;

Also, How we can replace below code snippet with hibernate-search 6?

```
    @Field(bridge = @FieldBridge(impl = ResourceAttributesBridge.class))
```

Comment: I already pointed you to the migration guide. Please at least make the effort to read it. https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/search/6.0/migration/html_single/#fieldbridge

Comment: Hi @yrodiere - I already went through this doc but didn't find information about this package import org.hibernate.search.bridge.FieldBridge;

Comment: Is FieldBridge interface removed from hibernate-search 6??

Comment: Ok, so you didn't even click the link I gave, which is precisely about `@FieldBridge`. I give up.

Comment: Yes I clicked on it but didn't find much useful info

Answer (score 0):

Judging from your (more complete) question [there](https://discourse.hibernate.org/t/how-do-i-use-fieldbridge-in-hibernate-search-6/6090), your actual problem is that you want to use the bridge to map a `Map<String, JSONObject>`. This means you don't know the name of fields in advance, which means you'll need to rely on advanced features of Hibernate Search.

In particular, you will need [dynamic field templates](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/search/reference/en-US/html_single/#mapper-orm-bridge-index-field-dsl-dynamic).

You can also have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66493009/6692043), since it addresses a very similar question.